# Linear Regresssion with sklearn giving incorrect results but somehow has high accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

My title is pretty self-sufficient so I'll cut to the code.

I made a simple linear regression program that predicts the stock data of Google. As you can see below I read it from a csv file.
Also, I get the stocks from the package pandas_datareader(YAHOO).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

epochs = 1000

data = pd.read_csv('stocks.csv')

data_x = np.array(data['Timestamp']).reshape(-1,1)
data_y = np.array(data['Scale Close']).reshape(-1,1)
plt.plot(data_y, label = 'Data')

reglr = linear_model.LinearRegression(n_jobs=1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_x,data_y,test_size=0.1, random_state = 4)

def fit(epochs):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        reglr.fit(x_train, y_train)
        print('coef:',reglr.coef_)

    pre = reglr.predict(x_test)

    print('FirstElement', pre[0],'FirstElementActual',y_test[0])

    count = reglr.score(x_test,y_test)
    return count, pre

accuracy1, pre = fit(epochs)
accuracy2, pre = fit(epochs+1000)
print('####ACCURACY1',accuracy1,'####ACCURACY2',accuracy2)
plt.plot(pre, label = "Prediction")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It gives me this output:

```
coef: [[2.92640722e-09]]
coef: [[2.92640722e-09]]
coef: [[2.92640722e-09]]

.
.
.
coef: [[2.92640722e-09]]
coef: [[2.92640722e-09]]
coef: [[2.92640722e-09]]
coef: [[2.92640722e-09]]
FirstElement [0.53657982] FirstElementActual [0.52925823]
0.0021231421871198554
####ACCURACY1 0.9232907005819857 ####ACCURACY2 0.9232907005819857
```

This looks perfectly fine until I show you the graph:
[image: Prediction of Stocks]

Why is it giving such incorrect answers but still having **92%** accuracy?

p.s. The number of epochs doesn't matter. Up above, I train it first with 1000 epochs and then 2000, and the accuracy stayed the same.

Oh, and also, if this is nessecary this is the csv file:

```
Unnamed: 0        Date         High  ...    Adj Close     Timestamp  Scale Close
0        1570  2020-02-28  1342.449951  ...  1339.250000  1.582866e+09     0.878272
1        1569  2020-02-27  1369.400024  ...  1314.949951  1.582780e+09     0.862336
2        1568  2020-02-26  1413.670044  ...  1390.469971  1.582693e+09     0.911861
3        1567  2020-02-25  1436.849976  ...  1386.319946  1.582607e+09     0.909140
4        1566  2020-02-24  1436.380005  ...  1419.859985  1.582520e+09     0.931135
5        1565  2020-02-21  1510.949951  ...  1483.459961  1.582261e+09     0.972844
6        1564  2020-02-20  1527.069946  ...  1516.989990  1.582175e+09     0.994832
7        1563  2020-02-19  1530.739990  ...  1524.869995  1.582088e+09     1.000000
8        1562  2020-02-18  1530.560059  ...  1519.439941  1.582002e+09     0.996439
9        1561  2020-02-14  1520.050049  ...  1518.729980  1.581656e+09     0.995973
```

Comment: In both your plot commands, you are just plotting the y data without passing the x-values. So it takes the length of the array by default as the x-values, which means starting from 0, 1, 2, 3,..... length .... Since both arrays have different lengths, they are plotted in the manner you see them in the figure. Pass the x-values accordingly while plotting.

Comment: Please notice that the term "accuracy" is meaningless for regression problems and is not actually used; what you calculate is the R-squared score.

Comment: Thank you! Sheldore. That seemed to be my problem.